# Printing parts of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

please excuse if this question is already answered elsewhere, but I just don't know what to search for, since I usually don't work with php.

I've got the following array:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [login] => name23
            [id] => 12356
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [login] => name12
            [id] => 12345
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [login] => name34
            [id] => 12367
        )

)
```

And I'd like to only print the login-names, so in this example `name23, name12, name34` (But I never know how many there are).

I've tried several approaches with foreach, which didn't work.

What is working, but only for one username is this:
`echo $contributors[0]['login'];`

How can I display all login-names as a delimited string?

Comment: array_column function in php does the thing for you. Please check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php. But even after using you have iterate those array to print the login name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_map` is a universal function for tasks like this, in your case, this code would work:

```php
$array = [['login' => "name23", 'id' => 12356], ['login' => "name12", 'id' => 12345], ['login' => "name34", 'id' => 12367]];
print_r(array_map(function($data) { return $data['login']; }, $array));
```

Manual: https://www.php.net/array-map

But for your specific task, `array_column` is simpler, as recommended by Aghilan B.

There is also `array_walk` function that can be used like this:

```php
$array = [['login' => "name23", 'id' => 12356], ['login' => "name12", 'id' => 12345], ['login' => "name34", 'id' => 12367]];
array_walk($array, function($data) { print $data['login'] . "\n"; });
```

That can be useful if you want to do more with the logins than just printing it, it would not need to iterate twice.

Comment: Thank you very much, the second one with `array_walk` worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[array_column()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_column.asp) Function**

```
    $array = [['login' => "name23", 'id' => 12356], ['login' => "name12", 'id' => 12345], ['login' => "name34", 'id' => 12367]];

    $login_array = array_column($array, 'login');

    print_r($login_array);
```

**Output**

```
Array
   (
     [0] => "name23"
     [1] => "name12"
     [2] => "name34"
   )
```

Use `implode(', ', $login_array);` to print as a string with commas

Comment: Thank you - How do I get from this output to just "name23, name12, name34"?

Comment: you need to print it as a string instead of array ?